# Cannot create a proper N Choose R Method

Tags: java, recursion, combinations, binomial-coefficients

I have this assignment for writing Java code:

Given a set of n items, how many ways can we pick r elements from n?  This is known as the “choose function” (or binomial coefficient), and we can calculate the number of r-sized subsets of n (where order is unimportant) using the recurrence relationship defined below.  Note that this definition builds on the notion of factorial, so make sure you understand the sample code first and have produced a working factorial method before moving on.C(n,r) = n! / ( r! * (n-r)!  )

I understand completely how the most simple form of factorial recursion works, but so far my code is this:

```
    public static int NChooseR(int n, int r)
        {
            if( n == 1 || r == 1)
                return 1;
            else
                return (n * NChooseR( n - 1, r)/ n * NChooseR ((n-r) - 1, r) );
        }
```

So for example if my inputs were 5 for n and 3 for r this method should return 10. I am trying to figure out how to write this method piece by piece so the code I have currently should print out 60, because (n * NChooseR( n - 1, r) should be the factorial of 5 which is 120 and n * NChooseR ((n-r) - 1 should be the factorial of 5 - 3 which is actually the factorial of 2 which is 2 but I get a stack overflow error. I've tried many other things am I'm to the point where I'm just staring at my code trying different things to no avail. If someone is able to answer this could you try explaining it like I'm 5 because so far no information on the internet has helped me and I'm extremely frustrated and I don't know where to go from here.

Comment: The code that you've written here doesn't match what you say you want it to do. You (correctly) want the code to compute n! / (r! (n - r)!). But what you've written has ti compute (n * (n-1 choose r)) / (n * ((n - r - 1) choose r)). For starters, do you see why that's what your code says to do? Then, take a step back. If you want to implement choose in terms of factorial, perhaps you should be making a recursive factorial function that and then using that to implement choose. Right now, you're trying to make your function kinda sorta return factorials and kinda sorta return chooses.

Comment: I don't understand why the current code I have up won't return 60, because in trying to understand how choose works I'm trying to write the first half of the equation, which is the factorial of 5 divided by the factorial of n - r, which should return 60

Answer (score 0):

First: Initial values are wrong for `r=1` since `C(n,1) = n!/(n-1)! = n`.

Should be `r=0` since `C(n,0) = 1`

Second : use this recurrent formula 

`C(n,r) = C(n-1,r) + C(n-1,r-1)`

 n,r goes to 1,0 in the end and identifies with pre-calculated initial values 
`C(1,0) = 1` and `C(n,0) = 1`